# Is my intuition correct?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Let $f : X \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and $A$ , $B\,$ two subsets of $X$ such that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

If I have that $ \inf \limits_{X \setminus A} f \,>\, \inf \limits_B f $, does it imply that $\inf \limits_B f = \inf \limits_{A \cap B} f  $ ??

Intuitevely it makes sense to me but I can't prove it. Any thoughts ? Or counterexapmple ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\inf_B f \neq \inf_{A\cap B} f$ then $\inf_B f < \inf_{A\cap B} f$.

On the other hand 
$$
\inf_B f = \min \{ \inf_{A\cap B} f , \, \inf_{B\setminus A} f\}.
$$
Hence $\inf_B f = \inf_{B\setminus A} f$.

However $\inf_{B\setminus A} f>\inf_{X\setminus A} f >\inf_B f$, contradiction.